# How to $sum a specific array inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the following structure:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "group_id": "A",
      "total": -1
      "items": [
        {
          "item_id": "a",
          "val": 1
        },
        {
          "item_id": "b",
          "val": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group_id": "B",
      "total": -1
      "items": [
        {
          "item_id": "c",
          "val": 3
        },
        {
          "item_id": "d",
          "val": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

given a `group_id`, I'd like to `$sum` the items values of this group and set the `total` value with that number (e.g. the `total` of group `A` is `3`)

How can I do that?

I know about `$unwind` but I don't fully understand how to do that only to the specific array I'm interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `groups` array
- `$cond` to check if `group_id` match then do sum operation otherwise nothing
- `$sum` to get total of `items.val`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge group object and new updated `total` field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      groups: {
        $map: {
          input: "$groups",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.group_id", "A"] },
                  { total: { $sum: "$$this.items.val" } },
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a8tmUu638Pn)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to evaluate `total` only for one specific group?

Comment: you can use `$cond` condition there, i have updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you consider this query efficient? because it seems to me that this query still calculates all the `total`s but filters them in the `$mergeObjects` stage.

Comment: i can not say this way is efficient, but I can say this is an efficient way than other ways.